# ¿Cómo marcar error cuando se presiona un boton y dejarlo así como en este ejemplo?

Tags: android, botón, android-imageview, design

Lo que he pensado es en cambiar el background o poner visible una imagen roja cuando se presione pero no sé si haya otra forma como en esta aplicación de FunEasyLern [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo puedes realizar mediante un selector el cual cuando detecte que presionas la imagen `android:state_pressed="true"` cambiara el color. Define el archivo `selector.xml` dentro de `/drawable` :

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#FF0000" android:startColor="#DD0000" />
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#5c0000" />
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

y define este selector como fondo en tu vista mediante:

```
android:background="@drawable/selector"
```